# See list of all remembered wifi connections (and disable automatically connecting to some of them)

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless

In Ubuntu 18, how can I list all my remembered WiFi connections (not just the visible ones)? I want to edit the options of some of these connections (e.g., forget them, or disable automatically connecting to it).

For context, here is the issue I am having. Sometimes I am in the Metro and my laptop starts connecting automatically to some network that I might have used in the past. I think this is not safe since I don't even remember the network in question. So I would like to inspect what networks my laptop is remembering and disable some of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, just found this under WiFi settings:

[image]

**Known Wi-Fi Networks** opens a dialog showing all known connections, where I can edit or remove them.

Comment: Can you accept this answer as the correct one? so people don't try to find a better option or something

Comment: @Kenivia Yes, but I have to wait 2 days before I can accept my own answer.

Comment: ah ok all good :)

Answer (score 3):

All the passwords are saved in this folder:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

to edit them, just go into that folder and delete the ones you don't want, or you could right-click on one of them and select `edit as administrator` and see / edit the info in there.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes here I found the offending network my laptop is trying to connect to in the Metro. But funny that there is no GUI version of this setting. I remember there was an "Edit Connections" dialog in Ubuntu 16 which took care of this.

Comment: I'm not going to accept this yet as answer, just in case someone else finds out an "official" GUI way of doing this. But thanks.

Comment: @becko you can right click on the wireless icon and select "Edit connections..." - is that what you are looking for? The same GUI should be accessible from the command line as `nm-connection-editor`

Comment: @steeldriver That's what I am looking for, but it is not available on Ubuntu 18.04. What version are using?

Comment: But yeah, `nm-connection-editor` from the terminal opens the desired dialog.

Comment: @becko I'm using 18.04 - but with the Budgie desktop. I didn't realise that the regular desktop had dropped that functionality

Comment: @steeldriver Apparently in the GNOME desktop the way to access that dialog has changed. But see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings, WI-FI.

Click on the hamburger icon then on "Known WI-FI Networks" menu item.

You can now delete or edit them.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out, see my answer.